# how to implement xamcheckeditor disable style

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

when you bind bool value to xamdatagrid, the column will automatically use xamcheckeditor to display the data. I want to use an outer button to control the allowedit of a checkbox column, and when i change the allowedit property, the checkbox in the column will apply disable/enable style(turn gray)
In my resource dictionary, i write a style for xamcheckeditor:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="PART_FocusSite" Property ="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
     </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

So when the field is not editable, the checkbox would show as disabled.

I also have a button to control the allowedit of the column, when the button get click, it will invoke:

```
grid.FieldsLayouts[0].Fields["Enabled"].Settings.AllowEdit = true/false
```

But the enable/disabled action is not applied automatically, i have to click the filter to refresh the grid to get them applied...

Please advise what should i do to implement once click the button to set the filed allowedit, the checkboxs will be enabled automatically.

Thanks!

Enzhou

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is disable/enable the XamCheckEditor when the field it belongs to has AllowEdit set to false/true then all you need to do is create a style with a binding directly attached to AllowEdit.

```
<local:NullableBooleanConverter x:Key="converter"/>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamCheckEditor}" >
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}},
        Path=Field.Settings.AllowEdit, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
</Style>
```

Since the XamCheckEditor is inside each cell of your Field, that means it's inside a CellValuePresenter.  You can use a RelativeSource binding to get to it and then access it's properties.  One of it's properties is the field it belongs to.  So knowing that, you can just bind directly to AllowEdit.

Now AllowEdit is a nullable boolean (bool?) that defaults to null so you will need to use a converter to make sure the data gets across to the XamCheckEditor correctly.

```
public class NullableBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // If value is null then we really mean true.
        if (value == null)
            return true;

        // value is not null so it's either true or false.
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

All you need to do now is set the AllowEdit property as you're doing originally and it will automatically update the XamCheckEditor.